# Multiple Static Libraries

Tags: ios, swift

I have six static libraries as archives [.a], I want to create a Framework or another archive in iOS, in which I handle them adding more functionalities, making it easy to use in the future. Is this possible?

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You should do the following steps:

1. Create one static lib from all: You can extract all libs into a folder with `ar` and after that create a new single lib with `ar` from these extracted files.
2. This new lib is the basis of your framework. A framework is nothing more than a directory with a certain structure (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html) where the binary is just your static library.